# Object Required, classic asp page error

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

i'm trying to send email and since that hosting supports classic asp so i managed to get the asp code for mailing but i get some error i.e. "Object Required!" or "Permission Denied!"
how can i fix it plz help code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Set Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="smtp.gmail.com"
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = 1

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="arthur.dent@example.com"
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="H34rt0fG01d"

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Update

Mail.Subject="Subject"
Mail.From="arthur.dent@example.com"
Mail.To="ford.prefect@example.com"
Mail.TextBody="This is Body!"

Mail.Send
 Set Mail = Nothing
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Response.Write(Err.Description)
End If
```

here's the link i'm using: 
http://www.realfashionstreet.com/v/vspfiles/Fortest.asp

Comment: Your code looks OK, although I think the setting for smtpusessl might be "= true" rather than "= 1".  You coult try rewriting using a CDO.Configuration object - see this link http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/how-do-i-send-e-mail-with-cdo.html

Comment: remove that `on error resume next` for debugging purposes.

Comment: @user2824642 man better edit your post you have an valid Google account in that!!!!!!!!

Comment: well obviously your Hosting Provider does not Support CDO... perhaps it has another classic asp email component. you can easily look that up at your Hosting provider

Comment: Try changing to `Set Mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")`.